# Adding a margintop or bottom to list items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list that contains texts and two icon images.  The text doesnt align with the images so I want to be able to add a margin to the links. However, after at least an hour of checking I still can't get it to work, here is my code:

```
<div class="company-info pull-right">



                    <ul class="social-header">

                    <li>Follow Us</li>
                    <li class="socials"><a href="#" title="follow us on twitter"><i class="twit-icon"></i></a></li>
                    <li class="socials"><a href="#" title="Folow us on LinkedIn"><i class="linked-icon"></i></a></li>


                    </ul><!--/social header-->

            </div><!--/pull right-->


        </div><!--/company info-->
```

[image]

```
    .social-header{
    list-style:none;
}

.social-header li{
    display:inline;
}

.social-header li.socials{
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: What's jQuery got to do with your question?

Comment: Why are you opening 1 <div> and closing 2?

Comment: sorry there was more html above, copied the wrong amount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

margin wont work on an inline element.

```
.social-header li{
    display:inline-block;
    float: left;
}



.social-header li.socials{
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

Comment: ok, ive changed to inline block, and now the whole three list items move and not the two with the class of socials.

Comment: change the margin to padding... Updated answer above

Comment: Thanks aaron but it still moves the entire three list items.

Comment: did you add the float?

Comment: The float did the trick, ive also added a clear so that the text underneath is in the right place.  also added a float right to .social-header now its working great!  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `display:inline`, change this to `display:inline-block`.

This is because inline elements cannot have any size, padding etc. Think of them as if they were a letter in a paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend reviewing the [`vertical-align` property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp), its options, and see if one of those will do the trick. I often use `vertical-align: middle`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have you image files, but I just snagged some off Google and added my own img CSS class. The key was changing it to inline-block and using the vertical-align attribute. CSS classes to as follows

```
.social-header{
    list-style:none;
}

.social-header li{
    display:inline-block;
}

.social-header li{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img{
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

and the html

```
<div class="company-info pull-right">
    <ul class="social-header">
        <li><h2>Follow Us</h2></li>
        <li class="socials"><img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/free-social-icons/67/twitter_circle_color-512.png" /></li>
        <li class="socials"><img src="http://inhouseww.com/static/assets/imgs/icon-linkedin.png" /></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```